# How often does android gather my location information anonymously

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I know that android has an opt in program for gathering location information. I'm trying to get an idea of how that data is being used to improve Google maps because I've noticed how much it's improved in the last month alone(crazy improvement).

My question is how often do you think they are gathering location data? Is it a constant stream? Is it when they realize my location is changing? On an interval scale (1 minutes, 4 minutes)? I think it's fascinating what they are doing and understanding how often they grab that data might give clues to the methods they use to improve maps. Thanks in advance for any information or ideas! :)

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is a largely ignored feature in Android called [Google Location history](https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0).

[This explains some parts of your question](http://www.howtogeek.com/195647/googles-location-history-is-still-recording-your-every-move/)

Comment: I don't think developer is looking for information related to location history!!

Comment: "“Google’s location service uses Wi-Fi and other signal to determine location more precisely and quickly, often with lower power usage than GPS. Some data may be stored on your device. Data may be collected even when apps are running."
That is from the the article shared. So it doesn't answer all the questions of the developer but definitely some part of it.

Comment: @Aniv is right, I'm trying to understand ***how often*** location information is collected. If constant polling occurred then I could deduce that they could determine entry points into buildings and the possible strategies they use to collect wifi data. If they polled every minute then they probably have a different approach. A jump high five to the rockstar developer who knows the answer! :)

Comment: Did you try WireShark?